# Trying to run a systemd service but it cannot find directory

Tags: java, systemd

I am trying to run a Lavalink server on startup using `systemd`.

Here is my `.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=Lavalink Server
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=bubble
WorkingDirectory=/home/bubble/Desktop/Project\ Proton
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar ./Lavalink/Lavalink.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, the startup fails. Here are the Journalctl logs:

```
Apr 07 14:45:44 sen-zen systemd[1]: Started lavalink_server.service.
Apr 07 14:45:44 sen-zen systemd[13520]: lavalink_server.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Apr 07 14:45:44 sen-zen systemd[13520]: lavalink_server.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
Apr 07 14:45:44 sen-zen systemd[1]: lavalink_server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Apr 07 14:45:44 sen-zen systemd[1]: lavalink_server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It says `Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory`
but, here is the output of `whereis java`

```
┌─[bubble@sen-zen] - [~] - [547]
└─[$] whereis java                                                                                                                                                                 [15:06:06]
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

I tried searching about this but I found nothing that really solved my issue. What am I doing wrong and could anyone help me with this?

Comment: A relative path: `./Lavalink/Lavalink.jar`. That may be what is wrong.

Comment: Note: it's not complaining that `/usr/bin/java` doesn't exist. The error starts with: "Failed at step CHDIR" - the directory is the problem, and in particular, I'd say the space in the directory name is the problem. Try using `"/home/bubble/Desktop/Project Proton"`, and if that doesn't work, just keep your stuff in a directory that doesn't have spaces in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this directory exist?

/home/bubble/Desktop/Project\ Proton

The error states

```
Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It does seem like this was the issue, I fixed the `/home/bubble/Desktop/Project\ Proton` to `/home/bubble/Desktop/Project Proton/` and now it works.. thanks! I should had tried fixing that before posting here